# How to solve CoreDNS always stuck at "waiting for kubernetes"?

Tags: kubernetes

Vagrant, vm os: ubuntu/bionic64, swap disabled

Kubernetes version: 1.18.0

infrastructure: 1 haproxy node, 3 external etcd node and 3 kubernetes master node

***Attempts:*** trying to setup ha rancher so I am setting up ha kubernetes cluster first using kubeadm by following the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)

***Expected behavior:*** all k8s components are up and be able to navigate to weave scope to see all nodes

***Actual behavior:*** CoreDNS is still not ready even after installing CNI (Weave Net) so weave scope (the nice visualization ui) is not working unless networking is working properly (weave net and coredns).

```
# kubeadm config
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
controlPlaneEndpoint: "172.16.0.30:6443"
etcd:
  external:
    caFile: /etc/rancher-certs/ca-chain.cert.pem
    keyFile: /etc/rancher-certs/etcd.key.pem
    certFile: /etc/rancher-certs/etcd.cert.pem
    endpoints:
          - https://172.16.0.20:2379
          - https://172.16.0.21:2379
          - https://172.16.0.22:2379

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# firewall
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       172.16.0.0/26
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# no swap
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.9G        928M         97M        1.4M        966M        1.1G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

k8s diagnostic output:

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
rancher-0   Ready    master   14m     v1.18.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-99-generic   docker://19.3.12
rancher-1   Ready    master   9m23s   v1.18.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-99-generic   docker://19.3.12
rancher-2   Ready    master   4m26s   v1.18.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS   4.15.0-99-generic   docker://19.3.12
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.106.146.236   <none>        9402/TCP                 17m
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.102.162.87    <none>        443/TCP                  17m
default        kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  18m
kube-system    kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   18m
weave          weave-scope-app        NodePort    10.96.110.153    <none>        80:30276/TCP             17m
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE      NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cert-manager   cert-manager-bd9d585bd-x8qpb                0/1     Pending   0          16m     <none>      <none>      <none>           <none>
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-76c6657c55-d8fpj    0/1     Pending   0          16m     <none>      <none>      <none>           <none>
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook-64b9b4fdfd-sspjx       0/1     Pending   0          16m     <none>      <none>      <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-66bff467f8-9z4f8                    0/1     Running   0          10m     10.32.0.2   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-66bff467f8-zkk99                    0/1     Running   0          16m     10.32.0.2   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-apiserver-rancher-0                    1/1     Running   0          16m     10.0.2.15   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-apiserver-rancher-1                    1/1     Running   0          12m     10.0.2.15   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-apiserver-rancher-2                    1/1     Running   0          7m23s   10.0.2.15   rancher-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-rancher-0           1/1     Running   0          16m     10.0.2.15   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-rancher-1           1/1     Running   0          12m     10.0.2.15   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-rancher-2           1/1     Running   0          7m24s   10.0.2.15   rancher-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-grts7                            1/1     Running   0          12m     10.0.2.15   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-jv9lm                            1/1     Running   0          16m     10.0.2.15   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-proxy-z2lrc                            1/1     Running   0          7m25s   10.0.2.15   rancher-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-scheduler-rancher-0                    1/1     Running   0          16m     10.0.2.15   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-scheduler-rancher-1                    1/1     Running   0          12m     10.0.2.15   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system    kube-scheduler-rancher-2                    1/1     Running   0          7m23s   10.0.2.15   rancher-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system    weave-net-nnvkd                             2/2     Running   0          7m25s   10.0.2.15   rancher-2   <none>           <none>
kube-system    weave-net-pgxnq                             2/2     Running   0          12m     10.0.2.15   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
kube-system    weave-net-q22bh                             2/2     Running   0          16m     10.0.2.15   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
weave          weave-scope-agent-9gwj2                     1/1     Running   0          16m     10.0.2.15   rancher-0   <none>           <none>
weave          weave-scope-agent-mznp7                     1/1     Running   0          7m25s   10.0.2.15   rancher-2   <none>           <none>
weave          weave-scope-agent-v7jql                     1/1     Running   0          12m     10.0.2.15   rancher-1   <none>           <none>
weave          weave-scope-app-bc7444d59-cjpd8             0/1     Pending   0          16m     <none>      <none>      <none>           <none>
weave          weave-scope-cluster-agent-5c5dcc8cb-ln4hg   0/1     Pending   0          16m     <none>      <none>      <none>           <none>
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl describe node rancher-0
Name:               rancher-0
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=rancher-0
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:17 +0000
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  rancher-0
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:35:33 +0000
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:47 +0000   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:47 +0000   WeaveIsUp                    Weave pod has set this
  MemoryPressure       False   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:35:26 +0000   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:17 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:35:26 +0000   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:17 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:35:26 +0000   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:17 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:35:26 +0000   Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:24:52 +0000   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.0.2.15
  Hostname:    rancher-0
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  10098432Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             2040812Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  9306714916
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             1938412Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 9b1bc8a8ef2c4e5b844624a36302d877
  System UUID:                A282600C-28F8-4D49-A9D3-6F05CA16865E
  Boot ID:                    77746bf5-7941-4e72-817e-24f149172158
  Kernel Version:             4.15.0-99-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.12
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.0
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.0
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                 CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                 ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 coredns-66bff467f8-zkk99             100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (3%)        170Mi (8%)     11m
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-rancher-0             250m (12%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11m
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-rancher-0    200m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11m
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-jv9lm                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11m
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-rancher-0             100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11m
  kube-system                 weave-net-q22bh                      20m (1%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11m
  weave                       weave-scope-agent-9gwj2              100m (5%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (5%)       2000Mi (105%)  11m
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                770m (38%)  0 (0%)
  memory             170Mi (8%)  2170Mi (114%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                From                   Message
  ----     ------                   ----               ----                   -------
  Normal   Starting                 11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Starting kubelet.
  Warning  ImageGCFailed            11m                kubelet, rancher-0     failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  11m (x3 over 11m)  kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    11m (x3 over 11m)  kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     11m (x2 over 11m)  kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   Starting                 11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  11m                kubelet, rancher-0     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   Starting                 11m                kube-proxy, rancher-0  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   NodeReady                10m                kubelet, rancher-0     Node rancher-0 status is now: NodeReady
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl exec -n kube-system weave-net-nnvkd -c weave -- /home/weave/weave --local status

        Version: 2.6.5 (failed to check latest version - see logs; next check at 2020/07/28 15:27:34)

        Service: router
       Protocol: weave 1..2
           Name: 5a:40:7b:be:35:1d(rancher-2)
     Encryption: disabled
  PeerDiscovery: enabled
        Targets: 0
    Connections: 0
          Peers: 1
 TrustedSubnets: none

        Service: ipam
         Status: ready
          Range: 10.32.0.0/12
  DefaultSubnet: 10.32.0.0/12
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl logs weave-net-nnvkd -c weave -n kube-system
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:15.989759 Command line options: map[conn-limit:200 datapath:datapath db-prefix:/weavedb/weave-net docker-api: expect-npc:true host-root:/host http-addr:127.0.0.1:6784 ipalloc-init:consensus=0 ipalloc-range:10.32.0.0/12 metrics-addr:0.0.0.0:6782 name:5a:40:7b:be:35:1d nickname:rancher-2 no-dns:true port:6783]
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:15.989792 weave  2.6.5
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.178429 Bridge type is bridged_fastdp
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.178451 Communication between peers is unencrypted.
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.182442 Our name is 5a:40:7b:be:35:1d(rancher-2)
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.182499 Launch detected - using supplied peer list: []
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.196598 Checking for pre-existing addresses on weave bridge
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.204735 [allocator 5a:40:7b:be:35:1d] No valid persisted data
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.206236 [allocator 5a:40:7b:be:35:1d] Initialising via deferred consensus
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.206291 Sniffing traffic on datapath (via ODP)
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.210065 Listening for HTTP control messages on 127.0.0.1:6784
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.210471 Listening for metrics requests on 0.0.0.0:6782
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:16.275523 Error checking version: Get https://checkpoint-api.weave.works/v1/check/weave-net?arch=amd64&flag_docker-version=none&flag_kernel-version=4.15.0-99-generic&flag_kubernetes-cluster-size=0&flag_kubernetes-cluster-uid=aca5a8cc-27ca-4e8f-9964-4cf3971497c6&flag_kubernetes-version=v1.18.6&os=linux&signature=7uMaGpuc3%2F8ZtHqGoHyCnJ5VfOJUmnL%2FD6UZSqWYxKA%3D&version=2.6.5: dial tcp: lookup checkpoint-api.weave.works on 10.96.0.10:53: write udp 10.0.2.15:43742->10.96.0.10:53: write: operation not permitted
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.052454 [kube-peers] Added myself to peer list &{[{96:cd:5b:7f:65:73 rancher-1} {5a:40:7b:be:35:1d rancher-2}]}
DEBU: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.065599 [kube-peers] Nodes that have disappeared: map[96:cd:5b:7f:65:73:{96:cd:5b:7f:65:73 rancher-1}]
DEBU: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.065836 [kube-peers] Preparing to remove disappeared peer 96:cd:5b:7f:65:73
DEBU: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.079511 [kube-peers] Noting I plan to remove  96:cd:5b:7f:65:73
DEBU: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.095598 weave DELETE to http://127.0.0.1:6784/peer/96:cd:5b:7f:65:73 with map[]
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.097095 [kube-peers] rmpeer of 96:cd:5b:7f:65:73: 0 IPs taken over from 96:cd:5b:7f:65:73

DEBU: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.644909 [kube-peers] Nodes that have disappeared: map[]
INFO: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.658557 Assuming quorum size of 1
10.32.0.1
DEBU: 2020/07/28 09:34:17.761697 registering for updates for node delete events
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl logs coredns-66bff467f8-9z4f8 -n kube-system
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.7
linux/amd64, go1.13.6, da7f65b
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
I0728 09:31:10.764496       1 trace.go:116] Trace[2019727887]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-07-28 09:30:40.763691008 +0000 UTC m=+0.308910646) (total time: 30.000692218s):
Trace[2019727887]: [30.000692218s] [30.000692218s] END
E0728 09:31:10.764526       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0728 09:31:10.764666       1 trace.go:116] Trace[1427131847]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-07-28 09:30:40.761333538 +0000 UTC m=+0.306553222) (total time: 30.00331917s):
Trace[1427131847]: [30.00331917s] [30.00331917s] END
E0728 09:31:10.764673       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0728 09:31:10.767435       1 trace.go:116] Trace[939984059]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-07-28 09:30:40.762085835 +0000 UTC m=+0.307305485) (total time: 30.005326233s):
Trace[939984059]: [30.005326233s] [30.005326233s] END
E0728 09:31:10.767569       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
...
```

```
vagrant@rancher-0:~$ kubectl describe pod coredns-66bff467f8-9z4f8 -n kube-system
Name:                 coredns-66bff467f8-9z4f8
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 rancher-1/10.0.2.15
Start Time:           Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:30:38 +0000
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=66bff467f8
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.32.0.2
IPs:
  IP:           10.32.0.2
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/coredns-66bff467f8
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://899cfd54a5281939dcb09eece96ff3024a3b4c444e982bda74b8334504a6a369
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:2c8d61c46f484d881db43b34d13ca47a269336e576c81cf007ca740fa9ec0800
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 28 Jul 2020 09:30:40 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-znl2p (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-znl2p:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-znl2p
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                -------
  Normal   Scheduled  28m                    default-scheduler   Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-66bff467f8-9z4f8 to rancher-1
  Normal   Pulled     28m                    kubelet, rancher-1  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    28m                    kubelet, rancher-1  Created container coredns
  Normal   Started    28m                    kubelet, rancher-1  Started container coredns
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m35s (x151 over 28m)  kubelet, rancher-1  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

***Edit 0:***

The issue is solved, so the problem was that I configure `ufw` rule to allow cidr of my vms network but does not allow from kubernetes(from docker containers), so I configure `ufw` to allow certain ports documented from kubernetes website and ports documented from weave website so now the cluster is working as expected

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking connection to Kubernetes API server?

Comment: hello @ArghyaSadhu, could you please tell me how to verify that? From `haproxy` node, I could do `curl https://rancher-0:6443 -k` and it will return me an `ok` as response back.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem ?

Comment: hello @Malgorzata, I did not solve it, but I tried to use those same playbook but provision on google cloud instead and it works as expected. I searched on google before and i think it was issue with multiple interfaces that vagrant has

Answer (score 2):

As @[shadowlegend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6914338/shadowlegend) said the issue is solved, so the problem was with configuration  `ufw`  rule to allow cidr of vms network but does not allow from kubernetes(from docker containers). Configure  `ufw`  to allow certain ports documented from kubernetes website and ports documented from weave website and the cluster will be working as expected.

Take a look: [ufw-firewall-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970433/ufw-firewall-blocks-kubernetes-with-calico).

**NOTE:**

Those same playbook work as expected on google cloud.